# Have a problem with swagger-ui and springboot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

this is the configuration and the dependencies i use :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and this is the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {                                    
    public static final Contact DEFAULT_CONTACT = new Contact(
              "test", "https://www.test.com", "contact@mycode.ma");

          public static final ApiInfo DEFAULT_API_INFO = new ApiInfo(
              "test api", "For signing pdf document", "1.0",
              "urn:tos", DEFAULT_CONTACT, 
              "License", "license 0-1");

          private static final Set<String> DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES = 
              new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("application/json",
                  "application/xml"));

          @Bean
          public Docket api() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(DEFAULT_API_INFO)
                .produces(DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES)
                .consumes(DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES);
          }
}
```

And when i use this path : http://localhost:8090/v2/api-docs gives me the json.
but when i want to use http://localhost:8090/swagger-ui.html doesn't work. 
thank your for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Try extending WebMvcConfigurationSupport as shown in below and override add ResourceHandlers and should work for you.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

public static final Contact DEFAULT_CONTACT = new Contact("Nagaraja", "", "email-id");

private static final Set<String> DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES = new HashSet<>(
        Arrays.asList("application/json"));

@Bean
public Docket productApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(metaData()).produces(DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES)
            .consumes(DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("controller-package")).paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();

}

private ApiInfo metaData() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("REST API")
            .description("Write description").version("1.0.0")
            .license("Apache License Version 2.0").licenseUrl("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0")
            .contact(DEFAULT_CONTACT).build();
}

@Override
protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what exact issue you are facing?

Comment: Please check in the logs for below mapping---  [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/swagger-ui.html] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]

Comment: Thanks i doesn't found any path /swagger-ui.html in my logs i just find v2/api-docs and others path of my controllers

Comment: Double check your pom.xml as for the dependencies (see above) and do clean install